# ItemizedOverlay OSMDroid

Tags: android, itemizedoverlay, osmdroid

I am new to Android development and Java so please excuse my ignorance.

I am having problems adding a pinpoint to a Mapnik map using ItemizedOverlay. I am following a Google Maps tutorial and trying to convert it to OSMDroid and I cannot get this to work.
In the class blow the error is highlight in red. I would be very much appreciate if someone with more experience could point out where I am going wrong.

**The ItemizedOverlay Class:**

```
public class CustomPoint extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context c;

public CustomPoint(Drawable pDefaultMarker, ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public CustomPoint(Drawable m, Context context){
        this(m);
       c = context;     
        }


   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem aOverlayItem)
    {
        mItemList.add(aOverlayItem);
        populate();
    }

    public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem aOverlayItem)
    {
        mItemList.remove(aOverlayItem);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
    {
        return mItemList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        if (mItemList != null)
            return mItemList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public void insertPinpoint(OverlayItem o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mItemList.add(o); 
        populate();

    }

}
```

**MainActivity class that calls the CustomPoint class:**

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here I am", "2nd String",(GeoPoint)touchedPoint);
    CustomPoint custom = new CustomPoint(d, MainActivity.this);
    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
    overlayList.add(custom);
            }
```

Comment: is the overlayList added to your MapView?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I am pretty stuck here. I have this code  List<Overlay> overlayList = mapView.getOverlays();
     overlayList.add(t);

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I am pretty stuck here. Is that not done by overlayList.add(custom); ? The difference between the tutorial I was following is the addition of the Resource Proxy... I would really appreciate some guidance here if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extend your class to **ItemizedIconOverlay**

```
public class CustomPoint extends ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context c;

public CustomPoint(Master master,ArrayList<OverlayItem> pList,Drawable marker, ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem> pOnItemGestureListener, ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
        super(pList, marker, pOnItemGestureListener, pResourceProxy);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```